# First-chance exception at 0x76F8277C in SensorTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've been following this [tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_Native_C++_and_DirectX_-_First_Direct3D_App,_setting_up_Touch_and_Sensors), but I'm getting this exception and it's very confusing. I enabled ID_CAP_SENSORS in the manifest, so that's not the problem.

The error happens when I try to initialise accelerometer or gyroscope in my constructor:

```
m_accelerometer = Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer::GetDefault();
m_gyrometer = Windows::Devices::Sensors::Gyrometer::GetDefault();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried native debugging? Are you debugging on phone device or emulator? If phone, are you sure your phone has got a gyro (many don't)?

Comment: I'm testing it on emulator. How do I use native debugging? Sorry I'm pretty new to WP development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test gyroscope code on the Windows Phone emulator at this time.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202943(v=vs.105).aspx.

> Important Note:
>
> You cannot test this app on the emulator. The emulator doesn’t support the gyroscope. You can only test this app on a registered phone.

Also beware that not all Windows Phones have gyroscope hardware.